# Connecting PHP script to remote Oracle Database Proplem

Tags: php, oracle, windows-xp-sp3, oci8

i am trying to connect a php script to remote oracle DB but after following [this article](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=784), I got this error message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: oci_connect(): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect
>   identifier specified
>
> Filename: controllers/cancel.php
>
> Line Number: 13

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Does the remote DB allow connections from remote location? confirm it

Comment: It looks like your `oci` is having problems finding the right database. From memory, oci uses an Oracle Instant Client to make the connection, which in turn uses a TNSNames file to list the connections. Have you got the right entry in there for the database?

Comment: Check whether your Oracle server instance is running fine and double check your connection string is ok.

Comment: You might not have heard of google, it's quite new, give it a try [with your search query](http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=oci_connect():+ORA-12154%3A+TNS%3Acould+not+resolve+the+connect+identifier+specified&oq=oci_connect():+ORA-12154%3A+TNS%3Acould+not+resolve+the+connect+identifier+specified&gs_l=hp.3...260.260.0.395.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1j2.JN5r6Y52adk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3d666e071cd6d452&biw=1320&bih=821)

Comment: i am using toad and it connecting normally

Comment: @dbf u surprised me with ur valuable answer :|

Comment: @AhmadSobh I always try not to be that ironic, but I do hope I surprised you with the first result where it said **[SOLVED] ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified  (Read 85354 times)**, and your welcome.

Comment: what if i told u that i have googled that for the past two days and i didn't find any suitable answer!!!, so don't put urself in the smart guy suit and others are dump :)